# should each presenter have its own service class or use BLL layer methods directly

Tags: asp.net, mvp

I'm developing a **MVP** project . now I wonder if I should create a **separate service** ( interface and implemented ) class for each presenter , only containing presenter's required methods . or no , It should connect **directly** to the **BLL layer** methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a good idea to use a Facade or Service Layer between presenters and BLL, It would faciliate dependency injection so better testablity.

But I think it would be better if you create these services or facades based on usecases so it would be more reusable between presenters rather than one service per presenter approach.